# Firebase Authentication is not working in ios using ionic 3?

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-authentication

Hi I developed application using ionic 3 and i added social media logins (Facebook and google) by following this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova and i completed all the setup. I tested this application in android it works fine but its not working when i deploy in ios device. i got the error "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server" and i found only one suggestion and i  tried by adding  'preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine"' tag added to config and run the application i get "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user" as response. I am not able to find any solution for this issue. please help me out to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error before adding preference in config]

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @SuatKarabacak no.